# Azure App Service Static Website routes.json doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-website-hosting, azure-static-website-routing

I deployed my static website (React app) to Azure App Service with `routes.json` to enable HTML5 routing fallback. My routes json is located in /public and is available under URL `https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/routes.json`.

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

The redirect doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  From your url address, I am sure the service you use is not `static web apps`. If you create `static web apps`, your url address should be like ` https://yourstaticwebapp.azurestaticapps.net`.

Comment: @JasonPan thank you for all these screenshots and explanations. I haven't tried it with github but I'm sure it works. Yes absolutely, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: The _routes.json_ file is now deprecated, but routing, overrides, and auth rules are all defined now in the [staticwebapp.config.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/configuration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Newest**

I think you confuse the two services `Web App` and `Static Web App`. The `routes.json` file only takes effect in [Static Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/routes).

[image]

According to the React documentation, execute the following command to create the my-app project.

1. `npx create-react-app my-app`
2. `cd my-app`
3. `npm run start`

Then create `index2.html` in the public folder.

[image]

Create a new repository in github with the name `reacttest`.

In the my-app directory, open cmd and execute the following command to upload the code to github.

1. `git init`
2. `git add.`
3. `git commit -m'init'`
4. `git remote add origin https://github.com/yourname/reacttest.git`
5. `git push -u origin master`

Follow the official documentation to create `Azure Static Web Apps Preview`. Check the release status in `Action` in github. You can see the default page after publishing.

[image]

[image]

At this time, directly add the `routes.json` file in the public folder in github. Continue to check the publishing status in Action. After the publishing is completed, you can see that the route is in effect.

[image]

[image]

When we visit the default homepage, we can see the content of `index2.html`.

[image]

If want see `index.html`, we can add `/index.html` in url.

[image]

Comment: Would you still see index2.html content if you open `yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net/non-existing-route`. Would it fallback to index2

Comment: @Andrei Yes. https://zealous-river-0dfc4da10.azurestaticapps.net/non-existing-route

Comment: @Andrei You can visit it.

Comment: @Andrei Is this the effect you want?

Comment: @Andrei I don't understand why you add `/non-existing-route`. Which article about this usage, can you share link for me, thanks.

Comment: you need the website to direct you to your index2.html regardless of the route. The reason is, if you Refresh the page on any route other than root, it will fail with 404 if you have no fallback route. It seems like it works for you. Is this because it's index2 and not index.html? :) I swear I've done all the same stuff and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It seems like it only works from GitHub, I wonder if that's the case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217112/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-andrei).

Comment: @Andrei I saw your url is not correct. You can check the screenshots in chatting room. There are two ways to create webapp. Good Luck !

Comment: this also makes perfect sense. Instead of using webapp I should be using static website entry from the getgo. great catch!