# Deployed Nodejs service does not work on Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I've created two pipelines: build and release for Nodejs app.

Here is the link to nodejs app repo: [azure web service](https://github.com/captain-yossarian/azure-service)

Here is the tasks for build pipeline:

[image]

Here is the wwwroot folder structure:
[image]

So it is look like all required files are present.
Despite that, I'm constantly receiving:

**You do not have permission to view this directory or page**

I've tried to add web.config file, but it did not help.

I have front end application on same App service Plan and it works, so it is no way that I have bad service plan.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried [continuous deployment with github](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment)?

Comment: You can get more details when deploy your project in `Action`.

Comment: Hi, @Jason Pan, yes, I have tried - here is the issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/60585
It woked once when I tried to deploy through VS code extension, but I'm interested to do my deploys through Azore DevOps

Comment: I ran into the same problem just now, I used my other subscription, and everything worked fine. So I suggest you raise a support ticket on the portal.

Comment: It may be that some areas or subscriptions are currently abnormal. It is recommended to consult the official and feedback the problems encountered.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. Because, 11 of August I did not have any problems with that

Comment: According to the official documentation, using vscode for publish projects, is the best way to deploy webapp.

Comment: If this problem is solved, it is recommended that you can send out the answer yourself, which can help more forum users, tks.

Comment: During request creation, I'm receiving report of my server issues. One of the issue is: iisnode was unable to establish named pipe connection to the node.exe process before the process terminated

Comment: I just deployed it via VS Code extension and it still don't work. I have noticed, that VS Code deploy did not create node_modules folder. What about web.config file? Is it required?

Comment: No. You just make sure you can run successfully in local.

Comment: You need to upload your code to github. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624444/azure-app-service-static-website-routes-json-doesnt-work/62691128#62691128

Comment: Then you need log in portal,  use  continuous deployment to deploy your webapp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219789/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-captain-yossarian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to deploy my service only after using [nodejs-docs-hello-world](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world) starter.

It is looks like `web.config` is a required file, btw, still did not find any meaningfull documentation for `web.config`.

Make sure your azure nodejs env support your js syntax (import from ...), in other case use webpack or typescript.

I'have found `App Service Editor` very helpful if you want to debug your code errors. See section `Output`.

I had a problem also with nodejs version, despite the fact I choosed node 12 tls during web app creation, I have noticed that my app used node 6 under the hood. So I changed default nodejs version to 10. See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/configure-azure-app-service-for-64-bit-platform-and-node-js/) how to do it

Also, I want to thank @Jason Pan for his help.

[image]